Possible to add a "back" history item from a scroll event? [Solved (except on Edge and Brave)] <kind of>
For some reason, my solution ALWAYS works in Firefox, and SOMETIMES works in Chrome. I'm going to debug it more when I get home - I don't know if maybe adding to maybe items with pushState or maybe adding copies of the same item breaks it, but it always works in Firefox, which is weird.
I spent HOURS to find this example:
https://kitaitimakoto.gitlab.io/scrollspy-example/index.en.html#smoothscroll
It does the 2 things I wanted it to do:

When you click an item in the menu, it smooth scrolls you to that section.
When you scroll, it changes the URL!

There is 1 thing I want to add. I want to make it so, when the user hits the back button, instead of taking them off the page, it takes them to the previous section. Now, if they click an item from the menu, it already does this. But, if they just scroll down through, even though the URL is changing, if they hit back, it takes them to the previous page.
Here is the repo: https://gitlab.com/KitaitiMakoto/scrollspy-example/-/blob/master/README.markdown?ref_type=heads
Btw, if you want to try running it yourself, you may need to run:
npm install --save sanitize.css
npm install --save intersection-observer
Thanks for any help!

Only took 1 line of code:


  onTargetChange(event) {
    
    var newTargetId = event.detail.newTarget.id;
    this.links[event.detail.oldTarget.id].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
    this.links[newTargetId].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
    this.element.dataset.scrollspyTarget = newTargetId;


    history.pushState(null, null, location.href); // added this 
  }



It doesn't work in Edge and Brave, but it does work in Chrome and Firefox. If anyone knows how to fix it in Edge, that'd be cool, but I'm glad to be living in a time where only %5 of people are still using Edge. I wish web developers would get together and just boycott Edge 1 day a year - replacing it with instruction on how to download Chrome or Firefox. The collective amount of time wasted because Microsoft wants to bundle a browser it hasn't got to work right in 25 years is ridiculous. I thought we were past browser specific bugs, but even in 2024 Internet Explorer is still a piece of crap. I don't care if you call it "Edge", the only thing it is good for is downloading Chrome after you fresh install Windows. It LITERALLY froze while I was writing this post, and I don't think it "froze", I think it opened a modal on my "second monitor" which is a television which is turned off. So I had to CTRL+ALT+delete it. The whole thing's stupid - it's hard to even find the version you are using because instead of being in the Help menu it is in Settings. How is the current version a setting?? I bet the people who work on it don't even use it. /rant
